# Looking for a proof of a result of Grauert and Kerner

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, stein-manifolds

I'm looking for a proof of the following result.

Let $X$ be a Stein manifold and $h: Z \to X$ be a holomorphic fibre bundle with a complex homogeneous fibre whose structure group is a complex Lie group acting transitively on the fibre. Then the inclusion $\Gamma_{holo} (X,Z) \to \Gamma_{cont} (X,Z) $ of the space of holomorphic sections into the space of continuous sections is a weak homotopy equivalence.

In particular, this implies that every continuous section is homotopic to a holomorphic section, which is the result I need.

Several sources which cite this result refer to a paper in German by Grauert and Kerner, which can be found [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01234962). I do not read German, but from what I could gather with crude google translate, the paper does not quote this result exactly (I could be wrong). This gives me hope that the precise statement of the theorem, and its proof, may be found in another paper which I am able to read.

Anyway, I have failed to find an English translation of this paper on the internet, and neither could I find another reference that provides the proof. Perhaps one of you could have better luck in finding one?

Comment: Try searching for “Oka-Grauert principle.”

Comment: Theorem 5.3.2 in this book by Forstneric https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-61058-0, which also contains a proof

Comment: @YangMills I have that book and the proof he gives, if I understand correctly, is of a vast generalization of the theorem. I do not find a direct proof of the above result, I would prefer the simpler proof of the older theorem I quoted if possible, but I won't be picky in the end, just hoping.

Comment: See Theorem 3.2 in Leiter, Holomorphic Vector Bundles and the Oka-Grauert Principle: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-61263-3_2

Comment: @JanBohr Thanks, that is almost exactly what I'm looking for, with fibres a complex Lie group instead of a complex homogeneous space. I'll take a look further in that book